# Torsion on thin walled members

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures

Is the formula $T=2qA$ valid for both open thin-walled and closed thin-walled members, where $T$ is torque, $q$ is shear flow, and $A$ is the area?

Answer (score 2):

No , the statement is true only for closed thin wall sections. 
$$ T = \oint_s\text{d}t = \oint q(h\text{d}s) = q \oint h \text{d}s = q \oint 2 \text{d}A = q(2A) = 2qA $$

where $A$ is the area of the section; $T$, the torque; $q$, the shear flow; and $h$, the distance from the center of the section to the wall.

Torque is much smaller in open wall sections.

Comment: if so, how do we find the torque for open sections?

Comment: Every section is different, but generally the torque capacity is much smaller for example in a C section than a closed section of comparable size. Extreme  caution is advisedwhen designing for torque in open sections, due to warping danger.

Comment: it is small but if we want to calculate it how we do it for example for a C section. is there any formula for it.

Comment: I already answered, every section is different. You need to find J torsion constant for that section and G. Then for an I beam  for example with no warning and only St Venant torsional shear stress   - T = phee. Gj/z.

Comment: I will modify my answer to add an example of an open section. I rather do it later on a laptop than on my phone, which encourages typo errors.